# C# LOC counting with GIT

Tags: c#, git

I was wondering if there is any tools out there that can report on the LOC for Added, Modified and Deleted code from a GIT check in.

It would be awesome if it could then add the count to a some sort of DB

Answer (score 0):

`git show --stat <commit>` displays changed files, insertions and deletions per-file, and totals. If you want to call this from a script, you can use `--numstat` instead which outputs it in a machine-readable format. (You also probably want to add `--pretty=oneline`, so your script can just skip the first line of output, after which the counts per file will be displayed).

See `git help show` and `git help diff` for more information.

Comment: Will this only count text lines? I would like to add extra logic into counting lines. For example only count lines with '=' or "if" or "else" etc.

Comment: This will just count total number of lines added and removed. If you want something more detailed, you'll have to just have git output the diff and have a script that parses it.

Answer (score 0):

As [mkarasek mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089488/c-loc-counting-with-git/3089571#3089571), any additional logic in `git show --stat` needs to be scripted.

You can start by having a look at this Python script: **[GitHub project git-loc](http://github.com/ITikhonov/git-loc)**.
You could inject some logic when parsing the `git log --reverse -p` he uses to compute the number of loc.